# group by where clause on one of the records hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Trying to filter the groups down to only ones with a participant with a session over 5 minutes.

my current query:

```
select 
U.session_id,
U.session_date,
U.participant_duration
U.email
from data.usage U
left outer join
  (select 
  distinct M.session_id
  from data.usage M
  where email like '%gmail.com%'
  and data_date >= '20180101'
  and name in
    ( 
    select 
    lower(name)
    from data.users
    where role like 'Person%' 
    and isactive = TRUE
    and data_date = '20180412'
    ))M
on U.session_id = M.session_id
```

Once the data comes out..

```
session_id   session_date   participant_duration   email
143          20180401       0.4                    huy@gmail.com
143          20180401       1.5                    t@gmail.com
143          20180401       1.6                    att@gmail.com
143          20180401       2.3                    m@gmail.com
124          20180401       5.6                    p@gmail.com
124          20180401       3.2                    alex@gmail.com
165          20180401       4.1                    jeff@gmail.com
165          20180401       3.1                    nader@gmail.com
```

I would like to filter this down with a where clause that only brings back groups with at least 1 record in them with `participant_duration >= 5`.

would like something like:
`group by session_id having participant_duration >= 5`

Is this far off?

Answer (score 0):

Yes..you have the right idea using `group by` and `having`.

```
group by session_id
having sum(cast(participant_duration >= 5 as int)) >= 1
```

Also your query can be simplified to

```
select *
from (select U.session_id,U.session_date,U.participant_duration,U.email,
      SUM(cast(U.participant_duration >= 5 as int)) OVER(PARTITION BY U.session_id) as dur_gt_5
      from data.usage U
      join data.users M on U.session_id = M.session_id and U.name=lower(M.name)
      where M.role like 'Person%' and M.isactive = TRUE and M.data_date = '20180412'
      and U.email like '%gmail.com%' and U.data_date >= '20180101'
     ) t
where dur_gt_5>=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **group by on session_id** field then you need to use **aggregate function (like sum,min,max etc) on the other fields in select query.**

i'm thinking **session_id,session_date** are same for the records so i use both fields in **group by** (or) if you don't want to use **session_date** in group by then you need to use any of the aggregation functions on this field like **max(session_Date)**..etc.

Use sum aggregate function for the participant_duration then use partition_duration in having clause to filter out only the records having value more than 5.

Only field left in select statement is **email** which is not in group by clause so i use **max aggregate function** to get only one value for the email field.

**session_date in group by clause:-**

```
select 
U.session_id,
U.session_date,
sum(U.participant_duration) participant_duration,
max(U.email) email
from data.usage U
left outer join
  (select 
  distinct M.session_id
  from data.usage M
  where email like '%gmail.com%'
  and data_date >= '20180101'
  and name in
    ( 
    select 
    lower(name)
    from data.users
    where role like 'Person%' 
    and isactive = TRUE
    and data_date = '20180412'
    ))M
on U.session_id = M.session_id
group by U.session_id,U.session_date
having sum(cast(participant_duration >= 5 as int)) >= 1;
```

**(or)**

**session_date not in group by clause:-**

```
select 
U.session_id,
max(U.session_date) session_date,
sum(U.participant_duration) participant_duration,
max(U.email) email
from data.usage U
left outer join
  (select 
  distinct M.session_id
  from data.usage M
  where email like '%gmail.com%'
  and data_date >= '20180101'
  and name in
    ( 
    select 
    lower(name)
    from data.users
    where role like 'Person%' 
    and isactive = TRUE
    and data_date = '20180412'
    ))M
on U.session_id = M.session_id
group by U.session_id
having sum(cast(participant_duration >= 5 as int)) >= 1;
```